# Directed graph where DFS returns on a node before all its child nodes are visited?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

> Give an example of a directed graph in which a depth-ﬁrst search backs
>   up from a vertex $v$ before all the vertices that can be reached from
>   $v$ via one or more edges are discovered.

My professor recently asked this question as a warm up to lecture, but never answered it. I still have not figure how that is possible. Why would it return if it's not complete?

I just can't see a scenario where this would happen.

It would never return, since DFS is (essentially) recursive and it can't return without having hit all base cases.

Comment: Hint: what does DFS do when it detects a cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following graph. If DFS will first go to the second node, it will back up even though the third node is reachable from the second.

[image: The example graph]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what does he mean by 'back up from a vertex $v$'. If he just means an encounter of parent node then the case is shown in the pic. $s$ is the starting node in the algorithm. Flow might return to $s$ before going to leaves of $v$ making the edge $(v,s)$ back edge.

[image]